# Only one direction handle on corner point?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, pen-tool

I've been trying to find tutorials to help me understand direction handles in relation to corner points. The screenshot below shows a corner point and direction handle but it is only on one side? I was following a tutorial of tracing this image and in the video I could see two direction handles on this corner point but for some reason mine only has only has one direction handle.

[image]

Comment: Yeah this happens when you continue a line when you jus click and dont make a tangent for the other line.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this instead.

1. When you get to a corner anchor, click and drag out the curve handle, do not release the mouse click
2. Then, hold down <kbd>Alt / Option</kbd>
3. Drag to position the second handle in the direction you want to continue, release both the mouse click and <kbd>Alt / Option</kbd> key, and carry on
4. With the Direct Selection tool <kbd>A</kbd> click on the corner anchor point. You should see both handles

[image]

If you want to practice your skills, [The Bézier Game](https://bezier.method.ac/) is fun!  I have no affiliation with the site.

Answer (score 0):

You can get both handles back with the **Anchor point tool** <kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>C</kbd>

Just click on the point and drag

This tool can also move each handle independently

[image]